# Issue in hive after upgrading to 0.13

Tags: hadoop, hive

We used to run the below mentioned query in hive and it was working fine but after hadoop 2.1 upgrade it fails.

```
insert overwrite table x
Select a.emp_id,a.emp_name,
coalesce(b.salary, 0.0),
coalesce(b.work_days, 0.0),
coalesce(c.previous_work_days, 0.0)
from a left outer join b
on (a.emp_id = b.emp_id)
left outer join x 
on (a.emp_id = x.emp_id);
```

I found the issue was like reading from the same table(x) and inserting into the same(x) causes the issue. Does anyone has faced the same issue.

error trace

```
Status: Failed
Vertex re-running, vertexName=Map 2, vertexId=vertex_1412109137269_13777_1_01
Vertex re-running, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1412109137269_13777_1_02
Vertex re-running, vertexName=Map 2, vertexId=vertex_1412109137269_13777_1_01
Vertex re-running, vertexName=Map 2, vertexId=vertex_1412109137269_13777_1_01
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 3, vertexId=vertex_1412109137269_13777_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1412109137269_13777_1_00_000015, diagnostics=[AttemptID:attempt_1412109137269_13777_1_00_000015_0 Info:AttemptID:attempt_1412109137269_13777_1_00_000015_0 Timed out after 300 secs
Container released by application, AttemptID:attempt_1412109137269_13777_1_00_000015_1 Info: Containercontainer_1412109137269_13777_01_000077 received a STOP_REQUEST
Container released by application, AttemptID:attempt_1412109137269_13777_1_00_000015_2 Info: Containercontainer_1412109137269_13777_01_000100 received a STOP_REQUEST
Container released by application, AttemptID:attempt_1412109137269_13777_1_00_000015_3 Info:Error: exceptionThrown=java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(ArrayList.java:844)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.shuffle.common.impl.ShuffleManager.constructFetcherForHost(ShuffleManager.java:322)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.shuffle.common.impl.ShuffleManager.access$1300(ShuffleManager.java:80)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.shuffle.common.impl.ShuffleManager$RunShuffleCallable.call(ShuffleManager.java:267)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.shuffle.common.impl.ShuffleManager$RunShuffleCallable.call(ShuffleManager.java:220)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
, errorMessage=Shuffle Scheduler Failed], Vertex failed as one or more tasks failed. failedTasks:1]
DAG failed due to vertex failure. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:0
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
Shutting down tez session.
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? If yes, can you post it as an answer?